# Uniqueness of spanning tree on a grid.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, puzzle, trees

When I was at the [Graduate Student Combinatorics Conference](https://sites.google.com/view/gscc2019/home) earlier this month, someone introduced me to a puzzle game called [Noodles!](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/05/19/noodles-review/).

The game starts with a collection of "pipes" on a grid (centered on each vertex), clicking on a piece rotates it $90^\circ$, and a piece can be rotated any number of times. The goal is to turn the final configuration of pipes into a spanning tree (of the grid graph), as shown in the screenshots below.

## Example

[image: An example of Noodles!]

## Question

We left the conference with an unsolved question:
Are solutions to this puzzle always unique? Or is it possible to come up with a starting configuration (on any size grid) that has multiple trees as solutions?

(The prevailing guess is that solutions are unique, but nobody could manage to prove it.)

Comment: This genre of logic puzzle is known originally as [Netwalk](http://www.logicgamesonline.com/netwalk/tutorial.html).

Comment: @MikeEarnest, thanks for the reference. Based on [this picture](http://i.imgur.com/MdNODB3.png) from [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/20j0u2/an_interesting_game_called_netwalk/cg494cy/), it looks like (some versions of) Netwalk are on a torus instead of a grid—although that presents an interesting generalization of this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, solutions are not unique. The four "T" shaped pieces in the grid below can be rotated into either of two configurations:

```
┏━━━┓
┗┓╻╻┃
╺┫┣┛┃
┏┫┣╸┃
╹╹┗━┛
┏━━━┓
┗┓╻╻┃
╺┻┻┛┃
┏┳┳╸┃
╹╹┗━┛
```

Comment: Based on the picture in the question, all three ends of the T shapes have to connect to an adjacent piece; you can't have one end of the T run directly into the flat side of a | piece.

Comment: It doesn't "run directly into the flat side of a | piece". There's actually a dead end "╸" piece in between, so this satisfies all the rules.

Comment: Oh, I see. I couldn't quite read it in your answer, but it showed up when I highlighted it and now everything makes sense.

Comment: Here is an interactive illustration of the solution: https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/net.html#5x5:9555c3c88a1eb6a9eb4a22356